# etc/host file entries match or not if not match entries then send a Triger

Tags: powershell

Here, I am new to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to do Host file entries should match every entry in a dynamic list of IP and DNS name entries from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. Any mismatch will fail the audit.

entries are

```
10.23.24.45           foo.com
10.24.45.34           domain.com
```

Here is my code.

```
"$Pattern = '^(?<IP>\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(?<Host>.+)$'
$File    = "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$Entries = @()

(Get-Content -Path $File)  | ForEach-Object {
  If ($_ -match $Pattern) {
    $Entries += "$($Matches.IP)  $($Matches.Host)"
    Write-Host " the values are $Entries"
    $FailureMessage = "IP and host entries are existing"
  }
  else {
    $FailureMessage = "IP and host entries are doesn't existing"
  }
}"
```

But this is not working for me. Can you help here

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting. There are extra quotes `"` around the code block. Are those in your code as well? [Edit] the question and remove those, if it's just a copy-paste error. While you are at it, add details to the question and explain how the code isn't working. Wrong output? No output? Something else? You never print the `$FailureMessage`, so there's that at least.

Answer (score 0):

A hosts file can also contain comment lines or comments after the IP and Hostname parts, preceeded by a `#` character. Your regex at the moment does not account for that.

I would create a lookup hashtable with all required entries and use that to find whether the hosts file contains any of these or not and as result create an array of PSObjects for nice formatting and easy filtering.

Something like:

```
$file    = "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$pattern = '^\s*(?<IP>[0-9a-f.:]+)\s+(?<HostName>[^\s#]+)(?<Comment>.*)$'
# create an array of Hashtables with required entries
$required = @{Ip = '10.23.24.45'; HostName = 'foo.com'},
            @{Ip = '10.24.45.34'; HostName = 'domain.com'}

# read the current content of the hosts file, filter only lines that match the pattern
$result = Get-Content -Path $file | Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } | ForEach-Object {
    $ip = $matches.Ip
    $hostname = $matches.HostName
    # test if the entry is one of the required ones
    $exists = [bool]($required | Where-Object { $_.Ip -eq $ip -and $_.HostName -eq $hostname })
    # output an object
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $ip
        HostName = $hostname
        Exists = $exists
    }
}

# show results on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Next you can send an email using [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) if any of the required entries is missing

```
# select the entries where property Exists is False
$missing = $result | Where-Object { -not $_.Exists }
if ($missing) {
    # here is where you send your mail message
}
```

Regex details:

```
^                   Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
\s                  Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<IP>              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “IP”
   [0-9a-f.:]       Match a single character present in the list below
                    A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                    A character in the range between “a” and “f”
                    One of the characters “.:”
      +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                  
\s                  Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<HostName>        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “HostName”
   [^\s#]           Match a single character NOT present in the list below
                    A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
                    The character “#”
      +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                  
(?<Comment>         Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “Comment”
   .                Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                  
$                   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

Comment: I just given IP and hostname entries for example but IP and hostname hardcoded here. but what ever uncommented entries should match if its fails end a audit fail report

Comment: @Rams The idea is of course that you fill in the `$required` entries yourself.. Here they just serve as example. The output is an array of PSObjects

Comment: My aim is not hardcoded IP and hostnames in $required field so just asking since i am new Powershell

Comment: @Rama So, how **do** you intend to enter the IP's and HostNames then? Why would that matter at all? Lots of ways to create the hashtable from _some_ source, even from user input you get from `Read-Host` for instance.. The code is showing you how to parse out the IP's and Hostnames from the hosts file and compare these to other entries you dynamically set in the lookup hashtable. That was the question, wasn't it?

Comment: Yes that was my query, how do I compare my IP and hostname dynamically. it would be great if you can provide the code for this one