# Registry key value matching string value out put using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Here, I got the proxy override key value from registry key.

```
$regpath1 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'  'ProxyOverride'
```

$regpath1 output is 'google.com;domain.com;foo.com'

But here I want to write code to match the each proxy string value  google.com , domain.com and foo.com if anyone the string is not matched then send failed output like foo.com is not valid proxy.

Any suggestions

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what you like to match and what you don't. Give examples about what you'd like to get for the example registry value. Do _not add samples as comments_, those are hard to read.

Comment: any one can suggest here

Answer (score 0):

To check if registry key's value contains non-allowed values, create a list of allowed values. Split the reg value to get a collection that can be processed with foreach. For each item, check if it exists in the list of allowed values. Like so,

```
# Registry data
$regVal = 'google.com;domain.com;foo.com'
# Allowed values 
$goodProxies = @('google.com','domain.com')
# Create an array of values from regkey
$regProxies = $regVal -split ';'

# Loop through values    
foreach($proxy in $regProxies) {
  # if allowed list doesn't contain value in list, alert
  if(-not ($goodProxies -contains $proxy)) {
    write-output "$proxy in registry, not in allowed proxy list"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how to get the values from this registry key " Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'  'ProxyOverride'"  value and assign to $regVal in above

Comment: @Rama This starts to sound the same as with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64534220/9898643). Once someone gives you a working answer, you start asking how to get the values to compare against.. Both questions are about **HOW** to do comparisons, not if someone can tell you what values are considered 'good' or 'bad'. That is something you need to decide